# Deploy a specific MarkLogic Database configuration using ml-gradle

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

Is there a CLI argument or parameter to deploy configuration of a particular database instead of deploying all the database configurations under src/main/ml-config/databases?

e.g. when I use the `gradle mlDeployDatabases` command, it deploys all the database configurations.

I am looking for an argument like `-PmlDatabaseName=Database1` that lets me deploy just the **Database1** DB.

`gradle mlDeployDatabases -PmlDatabaseName=Database1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of properties that can be used to either include or exclude resource files:

https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Property-reference#other-resource-properties

> - *`mlResourceFilenamesToExcludeRegex`*    New in 3.0.0 - regex that defines resource filenames to exclude from processing (exclude = ignore). Useful for when you want to exclude a set of resources when deploying to a certain environment. Cannot be set when `mlResourceFilenamesToIncludeRegex` is also set. No default value.
> - *`mlResourceFilenamesToIgnore`*  Comma-separated list of resource filenames that should be ignored and not deployed. Useful for when different environments require different resources to be deployed. No default value.
> - *`mlResourceFilenamesToIncludeRegex`*
>   New in 3.0.0 - regex that defines resource filenames to include. If a filename doesn't match this regex, then it will be excluded (ignored). Cannot be set when `mlResourceFilenamesToExcludeRegex` is also set. No default value.

If your "Database1" file was "Database1.json", then something like:

```
gradle mlDeployDatabases -PmlResourceFilenamesToIncludeRegex=Database1.json
```